# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause'

Tags: html, laravel, eloquent

**Title**

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `outcomes` where (`user_id` = 37 and todos.outcome_id = outcomes.id) and `outcomes`.`deleted_at` is null)

In my laravel project I want to get the list of all task there corresponding Outcome values but this gives an error

```
  public function kanban()
    {
        $outcomes = Outcome::with('todos')
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                  ->from('todos')
                  ->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
                  ->whereRaw('todos.outcome_id = outcomes.id');
        })
        ->get();
        return view('taskmanagement.cruds.user.kanban',compact('outcomes'));
    }
```

Here My Todo model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Todo extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    //Table Name
    protected $table = 'todos';
    //Primary key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [

        'todoable_id',
        'todoable_type',
        'title',
        'description',
        'admin_id',
        'user_id',
        'project_id',
        'priority',
        'outcome_id',
        'tasktype_id',
        'started_at',
        'due_time',
        'completed_at',
    ];
    public function outcome() {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Outcome');
    }

    public function user() {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function todoable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }


}
```

Outcome Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Outcome extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    //Table Name
    protected $table = 'outcomes';
    //Primary key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [

        'name'

    ];

    public function todos() {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Todo');
    }
}
```

Output I want basically
[image]

Comment: pls, show us yours DB structure

Comment: @OdinThunder plz check my model I've edited the text.

Comment: but this column is exist in database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my suggestion right, you might get result with something like this:Brakcets are missing in previous so I've edited, Now this one is working what I want actually

```
$outcomes = Outcome::with(['todos' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
}])->get();
```

Comment: basically I want the output like this https://imgur.com/Beb1OEa plz open this link

Comment: you want list of todos for current user according to outcome, or you want list of outcomes with auth users todos ?

Comment: your query is worked you have just missed out the brackets. Now it's running. Thanks buddy

Comment: Approved your edits, sry for my mistake, I didn't have ability to test it. Glad to help you)

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function kanban()
    {
        $outcomes = Outcome::with('todos')
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                  ->from('todos')
                  ->where('todos.user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
                  ->whereRaw('todos.outcome_id','outcomes.id');
        })
        ->get();
        return view('taskmanagement.cruds.user.kanban',compact('outcomes'));
    }
```

Comment: Try this answer.

Comment: @aviboy2006 what's the difference between this and above I've pasted?

Comment: `->where('todos.user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)` this is different using alias for accessing column.  in your you are using directly user_id. `->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)`

Comment: @aviboy2006 still same error occurred Basically I want to get output like this but problem is it show all todos where I want to show only currently logged user data.https://imgur.com/Beb1OEa

Comment: can you confirm column exist in database ?